# Hudson job setup

Tags: permissions, hudson

I'm trying to setup Hudson to build my Android project.

The problem is that jobs are started by user "hudson" that doesn't have appropriate permissions (my project is located in my home directory) so I'm getting "permission denied" in Hudson build log.
Here is the output of dummy task that prints current user name:

`Started by user anonymous

    [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2129720862026016628.sh

    + whoami

    hudson

    [DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: SipPhone 3rd party libs #2

    Finished: SUCCESS`

What is the best practice for solving this issue? Can I make Hudson to run build from my user?

Thanks

Comment: I fixed the spelling error in your title but do you really have a user named "hadson"?

Comment: Sorry for missprint - "hudson". I executed dummy job with the follwing output:

Comment: Started by user anonymous
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson2129720862026016628.sh
+ whoami
hudson
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: SipPhone 3rd party libs #2
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: you should edit your original question with this detail, Artem; then people will have more information with which they can help you out with useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution: it's necessary to change user in /etc/default/hudson
 config file (HUDSON_USER variable)